# Do pivots have to be consecutive across the columns or can their be a break?

Tags: gaussian-elimination

I have a 3x3 matrix as described below.

Is the rank of this matrix 1 or 2?

Or otherwise asked, is it okay to have "gaps" in the pivots across the columns?

$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right)
$$

Comment: It's OK to have "gaps". The rank of $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ is 2.

Comment: Thanks very much